# Unable to write to SQLite with error code 6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, database, sqlite

I am trying to write to a SQLite Database from a cross platform app created using AngularJS, Monaca and Onsen UI.

I have a view where the User enters a Username and Password. I read these details and save them to a Service where I can access them later with getters and setters.

However, when I try and write the details to the SQLite database from the saved service values, I get an **Error Code 6**. According to [THIS](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html), Error Code 6 means the database is locked. Why would the database be locked and how do I write the values to it if it is locked/unlock it?

In my code I create the table if it doesnt already exist prior to trying to write to it. Is this what is blocking the database? My **app.js** code below to show database processes.

```
var db;
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    db = window.openDatabase("myDB", "1.0", "My DB", 200000);
    db.transaction(createDB, errorCB, successCB);
}

function createDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tb_remember_me (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name)');
}

// User clicks the "login" button =- write details to Database
$scope.validateLogin = function () {
    // Open DB and write to it
    db = window.openDatabase("myDB", "1.0", "My DB", 200000);
    db.transaction(goInsert, errorCB, successCB);
};

function goInsert() {
    db = window.openDatabase("myDB", "1.0", "My DB", 200000);
    db.transaction(insertDB, errorCB, successCB);
}

function insertDB(tx) {
    // Get the User entered details from Shared Service    
    $userID = SharedProperties.getUserID(); // WORKING
    $userPIN = SharedProperties.getUserPIN(); // WORKING

    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO tb_remember_me (id, name) VALUES (?,?)', [$userID, $userPIN]); // Error generated here
}

// Transaction error callback
function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL with ERROR CODE: " + err.code);
}

// Transaction success callback
function successCB() {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To my common sense you are causing the block in defining two transactions inside each other.

You reserve transaction from database on this line:

```
function goInsert() {
   db = window.openDatabase("myDB", "1.0", "My DB", 200000);
   db.transaction(insertDB, errorCB, successCB);  <--- here!!
}
```

and yet try another inside it:

```
// called inside previous function.
function goInsert() {
   db = window.openDatabase("myDB", "1.0", "My DB", 200000);
   db.transaction(insertDB, errorCB, successCB); <-- in here inside the call you make another transaction.
}
```

So, the database is reserved from a transaction on the first db.transaction line and the inner function is what is causing the blocking when the another db.transaction is taking place.

Comment: The idea of a transaction is to take care no other action is made in db while one is open. Now you try to open a second one as inner one, but they just don't work like that. Once one is open, another just blocks db as you observed right.

Comment: I removed the extra calls to open the database but still get the same error. I am wondering because these are asynch calls, do I need to add a $timeout() perhaps...

Comment: I would concentrate to remove methods that use db.transaction inside a callback of another such db.transaction. Those affect the locks.

Answer (score 0):

I am basically going to paste a small part from sqlite documentation and explain it a bit cause in the past I tried to do a SQLite based webapp and I've changed the implementation at the end due to that particular problem

> To write to a database, a process must first acquire a SHARED lock as described above (possibly rolling back incomplete changes if there is a hot journal). After a SHARED lock is obtained, a RESERVED lock must be acquired. The RESERVED lock signals that the process intends to write to the database at some point in the future. Only one process at a time can hold a RESERVED lock. But other processes can continue to read the database while the RESERVED lock is held.

As it stated SQLite cannot do two write transactions as well, this brings the database to a LOCK mode (sometimes permanent with the only way of unlocking it is through copy pasting the file)

So you cannot make a multi user app using the same SQLite file. If you the file is per user then you must create a mechanism that will actually wait for a transaction to be completed before starting a new one

here is the full documentation https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html